# Make a list inside the dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame like below. I want to get a dictionary consisting of a list.My expected output is. Can you pls assist me to get it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the handy [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function in Pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Department': ['y1', 'y1', 'y1', 'y2', 'y2', 'y2'], 
    'Section': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'Cost': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
})

output = {dept: group['Cost'].tolist() for dept, group in df.groupby('Department')}
```

gives

```
{'y1': [10, 20, 30], 'y2': [40, 50, 60]}
```